# Need help whith xpath query

Tags: xpath

I have this html:

<ul class="page-numbers">
    <li><a class="prev page-numbers" href="...">prev</a></li>
    <li><a class="page-numbers" href="...">1</a></li>
    .....
    <li><a class="page-numbers" href="...">20</a></li>
    <li><a class="next page-numbers" href="...">next</a></li>
</ul>

Need to select the first and last li that contains an a-element with a number (not with text prev or next)
This xpath query returns the first li i need ( the li containing page number 1 ):

```
    //ul[ @class='page-numbers' ]
    /li[
        not(
            a[ contains( @class, 'prev' ) ]
        ) and
        not(
            a[ contains( @class, 'next' ) ]
        ) and
        position() = 1
    ]"
```

Having problem whe trying to get last li ( the one that contains page number 20 ). Have tried:

```
    //ul[ @class='page-numbers' ]
    /li[
        not(
            a[ contains( @class, 'prev' ) ]
        ) and
        not(
            a[ contains( @class, 'next' ) ]
        ) and
        position() = last()
    ]"
```

and

```
    //ul[ @class='page-numbers' ]
    /li[
        not(
            a[ contains( @class, 'prev' ) ]
        ) and
        not(
            a[ contains( @class, 'next' ) ]
        ) and
        last()
    ]"
```

But it does not work. The first returns an empty nodeList, the second returns a nodeList that contains all li with numbers (1-20).
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this XPath can help you:

`//ul/li[not(./a[contains(text(),'next')]) and not(./a[contains(text(),'prev')])][last()]
|
//ul/li[not(./a[contains(text(),'next')]) and not(./a[contains(text(),'prev')])][1]`

[Please, see how it's work from me][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQTJ2.png

Comment: A little modification and it works perfectly: [ @class='page-numbers' ]. //ul[ @class='page-numbers' ]/li[ not(a[ contains( `@`class,'prev' ) ] ) and not(
a[contains( `@`class,'next' ) ] ) ][ last() ]. Thank you very much!